# How can I change the z-index of .sub-head to appear under the .navbar-fixed for a hover animation?

Tags: css, frontend, z-index, materialize

I'm using Materialize.css Framework in Wordpress with _s customised theme.

The main menu has the desktop navigation with an animation on the .sub-menu.

The navigation is created by nav.php.

The mobile navigation is hardcoded and not relevant for this question.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="brand-logo left" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
          <img alt="DMA Logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/dma-logo.svg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger hide-on-large" aria-controls="primary-menu" ><i class="material-icons">&#xe5d2;</i></a>
        <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            // 'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            'menu_class'     => 'right hide-on-med-and-down', 
          ) );
        ?>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
          <br><br><br><br><br>
          <li>
            <ul class="collapsible">
              <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header">What We Do <i class="material-icons">&#xe5cc;</i>
                </div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/what-we-do/life-of-building-solutions">Life Of Building Solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/what-we-do/engineering/">Engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/what-we-do/facilities-maintanance/">Facilities & Maintanance</a></li>
                    <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/what-we-do/interiors-joinery/">Interiors & Joinery</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="bold" title="Where We Work" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/where-we-work/">
                  Where We Work
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
          <ul class="collapsible">
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header">How We Do It <i class="material-icons">&#xe5cc;</i></div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/how-we-do-it/as-one-team/">As One Team</a></li>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/how-we-do-it/using-technology/">Using Technology</a></li>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/how-we-do-it/with-24-7-customer-care/">With 24/7 Customer Care</a></li>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/how-we-do-it/with-24-7-customer-care/">Engineering</a></li>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/how-we-do-it/ensuring-compliance/">Ensuring Compliance</a></li>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/how-we-do-it/safely">Sefely</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="collapsible">
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header">Who We Are <i class="material-icons">&#xe5cc;</i></div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/about/about-dma/">About DMA</a></li>
                  <li><a class="waves-effect main-color" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/about/our-team/">Our Team</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="bold" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/why-dma">Why DMA?</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="bold" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/casestudies">Case Studies</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="bold" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/news">News</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="bold" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
```

this nav.php output the code i've created in here:

see working example: https://codepen.io/AUDesign/pen/VNYYrV

The structure is a fixed navigation (z-index 997 & relative position by default)
but the animation that make appear the .sub-menu elements on hover should have a lower z-index than the container.
The .sub-menu covers the main navigation, so when it animate, it slides on top of of the link, and it's not usable, or nice to see.

This was the reference for the navigation animation:

https://www.travelclick.com/home-9-1-17.html but I've used CSS only at this stage.

In my case it mainly works correctly, except for the z-index of the .sub-menu, I've tried for hours, but it always appears on top of the #menu-main

I think there is a pretty complex structure of z-index and position (relative/absolute) in the framework itself. So I'm wondering if there is a simple template for this case.

this is an example of a z-index structure I'm trying to make work, but the .sub-menu never get lower than it's container.
as the .sub-menu is generated by WP, I don't have much control over the output.

I've tried to work out some additional css, to force the z-index, but whatever i do it doesn't stuck under the main navigation.

How can i fix this?!

```
nav {
  z-index: 9999;
}
.navbar-fixed {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#menu-main {
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
}
.main-navigation a img {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
}

ul.sub-menu li,
.sub-menu {
z-index: -999999999999999999999999999;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: One problem is, unlike the travelclick link, the sub list (e.g. "How we do it") of your code pen is included within the `<li>` tags of your navigation menu. With such HTML code, you cannot put the sublist behind. If you have a look at travelclick HTML, their submenus have an absolute position with `left` / `top` defined

Comment: @Al-un I see what you mean. The #menu-main output a WP query, so I cant output just the .sub-menu somewhere outside the main container!
There is any other way?

 <?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'menu_class'     => 'right hide-on-med-and-down', 
          ) );
        ?>

Comment: I don't know how flexible you can be with WP so I prefer not to answer. However, feel free to add the relevant PHP code in your question in case it helps someone else

Comment: @Al-un added, hope it helps. Shall I create the 3 sub-menus separately in WP? to than load them outside of the main nav. On hover than it can appear sliding from the top but on a lower z-index. But I'm not sure how they can align and it seems tricky to maintain as a code...